# FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified:

Tags: fpdf

Quiero poner una foto dentro de un pdf, la ruta de la foto la tengo guardada en la base de datos en el campo foto
así que consulte esa ruta y la puse dentro de la variable $foto

y para mostrarla coloco:

```
pdf->Image($foto,10,6,27,23);
```

Donde reempleazando la variable debe de decir así

```
pdf->Image(imagenes/yo.jpg,10,6,27,23);
```

Pero me sale ese error de que no especifico que tipo de archivo es, soy nuevo en esta libreria de fpdf y anteriormente no me habia pedido esto, como lo podria agregar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de la librería FPDF, la funcion se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
Image(string file [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, string type [, mixed link]]]]]])
```

Donde:

```
file: nombre del archivo de la imagen.
x: Abscisa de la esquina superior izquierda. Si no se especifica se utilizará la abscisa actual.
y: Ordenada de la esquina superior izquierda. Si no se especifica se utilizará la ordenada actual.
w: Ancho de la imagen en la página.
h: Alto de la imagen en la página.
type:Formato de la imagen.
link: identificador devuelto por el método AddLink() o la url del enlace.
```

Lo que quiere decir que debes especificar el tipo de imágen que estas cargando en el proximo parametro de tu llamado a la funcion de la siguiente manera:

Tomando en cuenta que nos admite los formatos JPEG, PNG y GIF

```
pdf->Image($foto,10,6,27,23,"JPG");
```

o

```
pdf->Image($foto,10,6,27,23,"PNG");
```

o

```
pdf->Image($foto,10,6,27,23,"GIF");
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.